# how to read my files in template, django model filefield

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I created two button for my pdf files, a button to read and one to download. my download button works but I don't know how to open the file with read button.
can I do as I did with the download button or is there a special method to open the files

### models.py

```py
class Books(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics/cover/', default='pics/default-cover.jpg')
    pdf_files = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs/books/', default='pdfs/default-pdf.pdf')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### forms.py

```py
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = '__all__'
```

### settings.py

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

### urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('book.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

### detail.html

```py
<div class="row">

   <a href="{{ books.pdf_files.url }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</button></a>
   <a href=""><button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</button></a>

</div>
```

### views.py

```py
def detailView(request, id):
    books = Books.objects.get(pk=id)

    context = {
        'books': books
    }

    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)

def addBooks(request):
    form = BookForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('allbooks')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'books_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I uninstalled idm (Internet Download Manager) and my files open normally.
To download I just put download in front of href.
thankfor your answers

### detail.html

```py
<div class="row">

   <a download href="{{ books.pdf_files.url }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</button></a>
   <a href="{{ books.pdf_files.url }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Read</button></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that :

```
<embed src="{{ books.pdf_files.url }}" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

I will display the PDF in your page.

For better readability you should create a new page with the PDF inside it

Comment: I tried that and it does the same as the <a href=""> </a> tag, it automatically downloads the file, but I want to open the file